How to Read Sub-Directories with Expo StorageAccessFraework
Using Expo StorageAccessFramework, I have been trying to read all file uris in a folder selected by a user on my React Native app.
Essentially, I want to iteratively check whether an item in the selected directory is a file or a sub-directory, and if it is the latter, I repeat the loop, this time inside the sub-directory.
But when I try to read the sub-directory, instead of returning an array of file uris inside of it, StorageAccessFramework returns the file uris inside of the parent directory (the one the user has given access to) instead.
My question is, does Expo StorageAccessFramework not allow access to sub-directories even if user has given permission for the parent directory?
What would be a work around?
